# change margin color for a jpgraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am trying to change the color of the margin on a jpgraph. I cannot seem to figure it out. I tried `$graph->SetMarginColor("khaki:0.6");` but that seemed to do nothing. below is the code that generates an example chart as well as the sample output.  I am using jpgraph 3.5 if that helps.

```
$datay1 = array(20,15,23,15);
$datay2 = array(12,9,42,8);
$datay3 = array(5,17,32,24);

// Setup the graph
$graph = new Graph(300,250);
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;

$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing();

$graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

$graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

// Create the first line
$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("#6495ED");
$p1->SetLegend('Line 1');

// Create the second line
$p2 = new LinePlot($datay2);
$graph->Add($p2);
$p2->SetColor("#B22222");
$p2->SetLegend('Line 2');

// Create the third line
$p3 = new LinePlot($datay3);
$graph->Add($p3);
$p3->SetColor("#FF1493");
$p3->SetLegend('Line 3');

$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(1);

// Output line
$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Not used jpgraph before, but can you not find out what the output html for the graph is and then change the margin using css?

Comment: @RMcLeod I am new to jpgraph, but as I understand it, it outputs an image, not html code.

Comment: Is the edge of the image not inline with the vertical line over D? If not then I think that whitespace may be considered as the background, is there a way of changing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SetMarginColor` is one of two commands you need. You also need to use `SetFrame`

```
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetMarginColor('khaki:0.6'); 
$graph->SetFrame(true,'khaki:0.6',1);    // The '1' here seems to be irrelevant
                                         // I've tried much larger numbers with no
                                         // change. This is supposed to be frame
                                         // width (in pixels). 
$graph->SetBox(false);
```

This produces an image like this

[image]