# Transparent background in jpGraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm trying to achieve a line graph with transparent background, but so far, I can only set the background to a specific color. Since it's PNG, it *should* be possible though.

```
$linePlot = new LinePlot($plotData);
$linePlot->SetFillColor('#61a9f3@.6');

$graph = new Graph(300, 100);
$graph->SetScale('intint');

$graph->SetAlphaBlending();
$graph->SetMarginColor('black:1');
$graph->SetFrame(true,'black', 0);

$graph->Add($linePlot);
$graph->Stroke();
```

**Result**

[image: Graph doesn't have transparent background]

*Not transparent, but black*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetMarginColor('White:0.6'); 
$graph->SetFrame(true,'White:0.6',1); // The '1' here seems to be irrelevant
                                     // I've tried much larger numbers with no
                                     // change. This is supposed to be frame
                                     // width (in pixels). 
$graph->SetBox(false);
```

Reference: [change margin color for a jpgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741195/change-margin-color-for-a-jpgraph)

Comment: That's what I already looked up while searching. It doesn't render a transparent image.

Comment: Are you able to change it to Red or any other color instead of black?

Comment: Yes, any other color, but not with transparency.

Comment: Because the background is white, but once it isn't, you'll see that no matter what color and opacity value you set, it's not transparent.

Comment: What happens when you do not set any color ? comment setMarginColor

Answer (score 3):

Transparent PNG image: **$graph->img->SetTransparent("white");** works great!!!

Answer (score 1):

for me i have to put black instead of white to get transparency !

```
$graph->SetMarginColor('black:0');
$graph->SetFrame(true,'black:0', 1); //but this make labels/letters weird !!!
$graph->img->SetTransparent('black');
```

Now, when making multiple graphs in a picture, this doesn't work. I try making for each graph the transparency or to the final one (mgraph), and i get 'HTTP ERROR 500' (internal server !?!)